# Big Cartel Roadie Theme - Increasing the logo size on mobile

Tags: css, bigcartel

I'd like to increase the size of the header logo for mobile phone view only. When I tried adjusting the css on a test site the whole thing crashed. I changed these max-height numbers:

I saw there were calculations in the code for mobile - does changing the numbers possibly break that?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .header-home-link.has-logo {
        height: auto;
        max-height: 64px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .header-home-link.has-logo {
        height: auto;
        max-height: 50px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it would seem as though you are editing an existing piece of code so there may be other factors I'm not aware of. However, your current setup works by making every width greater than 320px set the height to 50px and every width under 700px have a logo height of 64px. This contradiction may have caused some issues, however, I know chrome prioritises the rule that is later in the code thus creating a window under 320px where the logo height is 64px. For a cleaner solution, I would suggest putting the height for the logo for all other screens in your main CSS without a media rule and adding a `max-width` media rule with a width of 500px or so for the height of your logo.

Also is there a particular reason why you went for the approach of setting a max-height and then setting the height to auto as opposed to changing the height of the image directly and then setting the width to auto if necessary?

If you're still having issues I can also suggest trying to isolate the issue by testing aspects of your code with simple statements you know will work.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. It is existing code and I'm pretty new at this. I think this will help to solve it.