# Big Cartel Roadie Theme - editing code to remove the zoom feature

Tags: css, bigcartel

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but came across a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025617/big-cartel-roadie-theme-increasing-the-logo-size-on-mobile?newreg=7e97a47c5c98406bb33fc2664b2d77ae) question about editing big cartel's code so thought I would ask.

I am [currently using](https://tstout2.bigcartel.com/product/presale_pack1) big cartel's Roadie theme template, and like everything except the mouse-over bubble zoom feature. I would like to disable that, to just keep the mouse pointer the same throughout the page.

Big cartel does allow a person to download the [code](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=kZJvJBVZqPEwFKn4EO0mYIbPAQ2IAbdM8oGX), and allows you to edit it, but so far, my edits (for instance, removing the quote portion from data-zoom="{{ image | product_image_url | constrain: 1500 }}" from the product file) haven't had much success.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT!

where you see this part of the code in the "Product" code </> (*not* "Products"):

```
 <div class="product-images product-image-zooming product-images-{{ theme.secondary_product_images }}">
```

ONLY remove **product-image-zooming**

weee!!! this was driving me crazy lol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Hey I’m in the same boat, I emailed big cartel and they told me to post here for an answer ‍♂️

I tried to change the code but can’t seem to find the portion responsible for the zoom
It sucks cause it’s such a good theme